# Masking an UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiwebview

I am working on an app that requires masking a portion of UIWebView. I am unable to find a solution for this. Any help provided by you will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Aneesh Asokan what do you mean by mask?

Comment: Masking means hiding a part of that control.

Comment: Try to put some Label on that area

Comment: @Aneesh Asokan Ok, can you define part? Do you want to hide some content? I mean, wouldn't adjusting the frame do the trick?

Comment: @Nick Weaver Yes Nick. I need to hide the contents in masking area. I will be performing masking in touches moved method. So based on the movement made the masking area has to be increased.

Comment: @Aneesh Asokan just to be clear, for example there is a link in your webview and you like to hide/mask it you like to put something over it, maybe a opaque rect which scrolls with the webview?

Comment: @Nick The webview may contain alink,some text contents, or image. What contains in it does not bothers me. Whatever may be it I need it to get masked with respect to the touches moved. And the area that gets masked may increase or decrease based on the direction of touches moved. ie; Left or Right.

Comment: @Aneesh Asokan hmm I am still not sure how this has to look out in the end. Any kind of example image or drawing?

Comment: @you just go through the link http://blogs.cynergysystems.com/2009/11/13/the-secret-behind-the-page-flip-technique/

Answer (score 0):

I would put a UIView (maskView) inited with a CGRectZero just above the UIWebView. Then based on your logic you can resize the maskView and place in the position you need to cover the UIWebView content.